# Error faced in trying to install Java 8 on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: ubuntu, java-8, raspberry-pi

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to install Java 8 on Raspberry Pi 4B, this same method works for Raspberry Pi 3B.

Command used:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-java : Breaks: openjdk-8-jre-headless (< 8u382~b04-2~) but 8u312-b07-1+rpi1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can someone please help me out?